# How do I extend an electrical box?

Tags: electrical

In my garage I have a 4 outlet receptacle on the wall.

I would like to put a receptacle on the other side of the garage for use when doing outside work or vacuuming the car (instead of running a long extension cord).

*I don't want to open up the wall and fish wire through the 14' ceiling.*

I'm considering UF-B 14/2 through a conduit up and over to the other side and a plug for use when I need it; like this drawing:

[image]

is there any safety or code issues I am missing?

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing box you want to take power from?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  The graphic (in the red rectangle) is what is in the wall now. To the left is what I was thinking of creating

Comment: **This plan is 100% a safety hazard!** If you'll note, every outlet in your house/garage has a female connector surrounded by plastic. The plastic acts as an electrical insulator to protect the live wires from accidental contact. Temporary loads (lights, compressors, saws, refrigerators, etc.) all have male connectors with exposed prongs. These prongs are only exposed for moments while the plug is inserted/removed, and once removed, there is _no current_ present to flow through a person or metal item that could touch them. (Con't...)

Comment: Your plan is to reverse this and provide permanent current to exposed metal prongs. If this is unplugged (and why wouldn't it be, after all, it's just an extension cord going somewhere and I need that 4th outlet), there is now current just waiting there to zap someone!  **DO NOT DO THIS**

Comment: @FreeMan  Ok.  I see your point.  So what is there difference with this:  https://www.ebay.com/p/17014654479

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to accept and install surface wiring you might as well fully embrace it. Don't connect to the existing receptacle with a plug; instead add an "extension box" at that existing receptacle and run the surface conduit directly into that to make the connection permanent.

As for the proposed UF-B cable -- don't use that; it'll be unnecessarily difficult to work with. The location is dry so NM-B cable is an option (but don't use that, either). Pulling UF-B through conduit would seem impossible; pulling NM-B through conduit is still difficult, and either would require oversize conduit. Because you're going to install conduit the wiring can be even easier: use loose THHN/THWN/etc conductors. You'll be able to use 1/2" conduit and those conductors will practically pull themselves through it.

The 14/2 size is likely wrong also: if you've confirmed that the existing receptacle is truly on a 15 amp circuit then 14 gauge is OK, but circuits in a garage are often 20 amp. In that case you'll need 12 gauge conductors.

The conduit could be PVC as pictured, EMT, or a flat type designed for surface wiring. Wiremold is a brand name of one such kind of "surface raceway;" there are other brands too.

Here's a photo of a project somebody did with the Wiremold products. One of the outlets was existing and was flush to the wall surface. They've added an extension (in this case the "Wiremold surface conduit starter box") to get up onto the surface of the wall, then conduit/raceway and a surface box with another outlet. ([Kevin Standlee, "New Outlet"](https://kevin-standlee.livejournal.com/2041621.html))

[image: surface raceway outlets]

If you don't like or can't easily obtain the Wiremold products something similar might be done with cast aluminum or drawn steel parts. A steel 2-gang box was easy enough to find, but I've come up empty in my search for a steel 2-gang extension box (1-gang handy box extension, 1-gang to 2-gang adapter, and 4-11/16" extension are easy to find). I'm thinking it could be achieved with a 4-square extension box with a 2-gang device ring on both sides of the extension.

[image: weatherproof extension box]

[image: 4-square extension]

[image: 2-device ring for 4-square box]

Comment: This is a good solution and looks much more professional with very little extra cost or effort.

Comment: I think OP would benefit from instructions on how to **most easily** attach surface conduit to existing flush receptacle in wall.  I'm not sure about this myself and it seems like the most challenging piece.  The most obvious way, opening up the wall, would make the project much bigger.

Comment: @jay613 extension box.  If it's wiremold then a Surface Conduit Starter Box.

Comment: If using conduit on surface then you can extend the original outlet box with a Raco 187. For two outlet box position rectangle hole horizontal and mount to existing box through screw holes in 187 box. For single you could use a Raco 665.

Comment: @Greg Hill  So you think it's not a safety issue, but more of an aesthetic and difficulty issue?

Comment: @Marinaio While you _can_ run the UF-B through conduit if you choose (bad idea for the reasons listed above), you _cannot_ put a plug on it to plug it into one outlet to power the other one. When you pull that plug out, you will have _hot connectors_ completely exposed for anyone or anything to touch, causing a short which could kill a person or start a fire. **Your plan is 100% a safety issue!** Anyone in the future will _not_ know that the plug is the _supply_ side - _everyone_ will assume that it is a load and it is safe to pull that plug out.

Comment: Greg- _please_ edit to include the danger of having power flowing to that **plug** as the OP seems to want to do!

Comment: @Marinaio The truth is I'm not entirely certain about what code has to say on the subject of attaching a cord end (the male plug) to a building cable (UF-B/NM-B), but I'm skeptical of it. I know a cord end can be installed on e.g. SO or SJ cordage, but cordage can't be used for permanent building wiring. To use UF/NM cable to cross the room and cordage for the final feet to the cord end requires some junction box at the splice point. All those questions can be avoided by ditching the plug and adding an extension box.

Comment: @FreeMan I think OP wants to build a permanently installed extension cord. The receps on the red wall on the right are the source of power; the male plug is dead until plugged into those receps. At that point the gray receps on the left side of the image become energized. I don't think OP is looking to build a "suicide cord" with an energized male plug.

Comment: Hrm... I was seeing the exact opposite. Maybe OP will respond for clarity. If so, I'll happily delete my warnings. "Suicide cord" that's a very appropriate term and much more succinct!

Comment: @FreeMan "suicide cord" is a term sometimes used to refer to the male-to-male jumper cord a person can envision using to connect a portable generator into a house electrical system during some power outage emergency. (Of course, a transfer switch, inlet connector, and male-to-female extension cord are the proper combination for that scenario.) This wouldn't be exactly the same, but the term fit well enough. :-)

Comment: @GregHill  "I think OP wants to build a permanently installed extension cord. "  Basically correct.

Comment: @Marinaio -- *why* are you wanting to build such a thing instead of using a fully hardwired method?